# unordered_map element display

Tags: c++, unordered-map

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <unordered_map>
 #include <iostream> 
 using namespace std;

 typedef tr1::unordered_map<int, int>MyMap ;

 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
 {
    MyMap PolicyMap;
    PolicyMap.insert(Myap::value_type(0, 10));
    PolicyMap.insert(Myap::value_type(1, 20));
    PolicyMap.insert(Myap::value_type(2, 30));

    for (Myap::const_iterator i = PolicyMap.begin(); i != PolicyMap.end() ; i++)
    {
      cout << " [" << i->first << ", " << i->second << "]" << endl;
    } 
return 0;
```

}

why the output of above code is [0, 10], [2, 30], [1, 20] . it should be [2, 30], [1, 20], [0, 10]. it is happening only if i start entering key values from zero,  please help

Comment: The name `unordered_map` obviously was not enough to get the point across. If you want the container to be *ordered*, **why don't you use `map` instead?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently misusing `unordered_map`. This container advertises that *it does not keep its elements in any particular order*, so the result should not be unexpected.

You should use an (ordered) `std::map` instead:

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>  // needed for std::greater<>

// The third template argument defines the sort direction for the map
// std::greater results in the map being ordered descending (and always by key)
typedef std::map<int, int, std::greater<int> > MyMap;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the point of `unordered_map`. It doesn't sort elements like a `map` does, nor does it leave the elements in the same order that you put them in, it makes no guarantee as to which order the elements will be in in the underlying structure or the order the elements will be returned in when using an iterator.

The above allows the C++ implementation to use a more efficient underlying structure (a hash table).